# How do i use a Network Security Group to only allow my web app to communicate with my web service

Tags: web-services, azure, networking, network-security-groups, app-service-environment

I've got all the resources i need. I put my web service inside a app service environment, then attached the NSG to the subnet that the app service environment uses. I then allowed apps inside the VNET to communicate with the web service but it doesn't work proplerly. What exactly security rules do i need?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want an [ILB ASE](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-environment-with-internal-load-balancer/) instead, since there's no point in exposing your App Service Environment through a VIP (Public IP) if all you care about is accessing it from inside your Virtual Network.

From https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-environment-with-internal-load-balancer/:

> An ASE can be deployed with an internet accessible endpoint **or with an IP address in your VNet**. In order to set the IP address to a VNet address you need to deploy your ASE with an Internal Load Balancer(ILB).
>
> When your ASE is configured with an ILB you provide:
>
> - your own domain or subdomain. but you can configure it either way.
> - the certificate used for HTTPS
> - DNS management for your subdomain
>
> In return, you can do things such as:
>
> - **host intranet applications**, like line of business applications, securely in the cloud which you access through a Site to Site or ExpressRoute VPN
> - **host apps in the cloud that are not listed in public DNS servers**
> - create internet isolated backend apps which your front end apps can securely integrate with

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have you WebApp is used on the public network (Internet) and the WebService is inside Azure VM/Service.

You have to create Rules for allowing traffic to your WebService, inbound to the specific port you are using like

Name: AllowInternetInbound
Priority: AnyNumberBelowYourDenyAll  100 is a good example
SourceIP: INTERNET   use the TAG option
SourcePort: *
DestinationIP: YourWebServiceIP
Port: YourWebServicePort or *
Protocol: http or https
Access: Allow

Documentation:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/

If you post how your app and config are currently maybe we can see if there's anything missing.